# How to retrieve dependencies (embeded reources from Html) using HTTP request in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am trying HTTP request (Get method using Jmeter) to one of the Html page from Server. And I am unable to find embedded resources from the server IIS Log.

Can any one tell the solution, it will be very helpfull for me.

Answer (score 2):

Look for a checkbox at the bottom of the HTTP Request sampler that says:

```
[ ] Retrieve All Embedded Resources from HTML files
```

Just check it and JMeter will request all included files such as images, css, javascript etc.

Please note that this will NOT execute any javascript on the page which might make additional requests (like the google analytics JS that makes a call to the google analytics servers).